# Could mosses absorb enough carbon dioxide indoor?

Tags: moss

My house is located in a polluted area.
So if I want to ventilate indoors I get in lots of dust.
I'm absolutely stuck in the middle ..
What I thought first was that growing some species which are good at purifying but I realized that to absorb enough CO2 emitted from one person
substantial amounts of plants are needed.
So I found another one here!

[image]

called city tree.
If i read correctly,mosses used in there was
much more efficient than normal plants.
What i am wondering is whether any mosses can make same effect like 'City Tree'.
and whethere absorb enough amount of co2 (emited from one person) with Realistic amount of mosses.
Somebody help me T.T

Comment: That looks like the project in Amsterdam, it is very expensive and there is not real prove that is cleans the air... The project is placed in a busy street with fine dust of cars. CO2 is not pollution, it is a greenhouse gas, but not really toxic to humans when enough oxygen is present.

Comment: You might find this book useful.  https://www.amazon.com/How-Grow-Fresh-Air-Plants/dp/0140262431 written by a scientist working for NASA to purify air with houseplants.

Comment: The "science" in the book above is more than 20 years old. Some of the results were found to be mistaken (soil and bacteria had a significant contribution). "Wolverton says that, absent expensive testing, it’s impossible to guess how many plants might be needed to clean a room of its contaminants." In other words, his study was anecdotal rather than scientific. Proceed with caution, this appears to be the next big health hoax designed to separate fools from their money.